# C program Need help fixing my code for a word sort program

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Hi I am still new to c and have been working on this word sort program for some time now. the guidelines are:

Write a program that sorts a series of words entered by the user. Assume that each word is no more than 20 characters long. Stop reading when the user enters an empty word. Store each word in a dynamically allocated string, using an array of pointers (use the read_line function). After all lines have been read sort the array. Then use a loop to print the words in sorted order.

The problem I seem to be having is that the program will accept words but when I enter the empty word it goes to a new line and nothing happens. An help or advice would be greatly appreciated. here is my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define LEN 20
#define LIM 20

int read_line(char str[], int n);
void sort_str(char *list[], int n);
int alpha_first(char *list[], int min_sub, int max_sub);


int main(void)
{
    char *list[LIM];
    char *alpha[LIM];
    char word_str[LEN];
    int word, i, j,  num_count = 0;

    for(;;){

        printf("Enter a word: ");
        scanf("%s", &word);
        if(word == NULL)
            break;
        else
            read_line(word_str, LEN);
            list[i] = malloc(strlen(word_str) + 1);
            strcpy(list[i], word_str);
            alpha[i] = list[i];     
    }


    sort_str(alpha, i);

        for(i = 0; i < num_count; ++i){
        printf("Sorted: ");
        puts(list[i]);
    }   

    return (0);
}

int read_line(char str[], int n)
{
    int ch, i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
        if (i < n)
            str[i++] = ch;
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void sort_str(char *list[], int n)
{

    int   i, index_of_min; 
    char *temp;

    for  (i= 0;  i < n - 1;  ++i) {
        index_of_min = alpha_first(list, i, n - 1);

        if (index_of_min != i) {
            temp = list[index_of_min];
            list[index_of_min] = list[i];
            list[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}


int alpha_first(char *list[], int min_sub, int max_sub){
    int i, first;

    first = min_sub;
    for(i = min_sub + 1; i <= max_sub; ++i){
        if(strcmp(list[i], list[first]) < 0){
           first = i;
        }
   }
return (first);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `empty word`? what is that? is it word `'empty'`? or just `spaces`?

Comment: Why are you scanffing a char array into an integer var, (scanf("%s", &word)?

Comment: empty word would be just pressing enter without typing a word.

Comment: I was scanfing the char array into an integer var because it was suggested I do something like that for the read_line function. is there an easier or better way to acomplish that?

Comment: I would advise putting `{}` in your while statement for the function `read_line`. Just because you are indenting code doesn't mean the compiler is reading it as such.

Also, you indicate you want to stop the loop if `word == NULL` but shouldn't it be `word == \n`?

Comment: Everybody's answers and suggestions were awesome, finally got it up and running. Thank you guys very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic flow is flawed.  If a word is entered, the scanf() will eat it from stdin and store a null-terminated string at the address of the integer 'word'.  Any more than 3/7 chars entered, (32/64 bit, allowing for the null terminator), will start corrupting the stack.  read_line() will then only have the line terminator to read from stdin, (assuming the UB doesn't blow it up first).

Comment: What would you suggest I do? should i get rid of scanf() and use fgets() or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I seem to be having is that the program will accept words but when I enter the empty word it goes to a new line and nothing happens.

There are several problems with this:

```
char word_str[LEN];
int word, i, j,  num_count = 0;

/* ... */

    scanf("%s", &word);
    if(word == NULL)
        break;
```

First, `scanf("%s", &word)` scans whitespace-delimited strings, and to that end it *skips leading whitespace*, including newlines.  You cannot read an "empty word" that way, though you can fail to read a word at all if the end of the input is reached (or an I/O error occurs) before any non-whitespace characters are scanned.

Second, you are passing an inappropriate pointer to `scanf()`.  You *should* pass a pointer to a character array, but you instead pass a pointer to an `int`.  It looks like maybe you wanted to scan into `word_str` instead of into `word`.

Third, your `scanf()` format does not protect against buffer overflow.  You should provide a field width to limit how many characters can be scanned.  Moreover, you need to be sure to leave room for a string terminator.

Fourth, you do not check the return value of `scanf()`.  If it fails to match any characters to the field, then it will not store any.  Since it returns the number of fields that were successfully scanned (or an error indicator), you can detect this condition.

One way to correct the `scanf()` and "empty word" test would be:

```
int result;

result = scanf("%*[ \t]%19[^ \t\n]", word_str);
if (result < 1) break;
```

(That assumes a fixed maximum word length of 19 to go with your declared array length of 20.)  You have several additional problems in your larger code, large among them that `read_line()` attempts to read the same data you just read via `scanf()` (in fact, that function looks altogether pointless).  Also, you never update `num_count`, and after calling `sort_str()` you lose track of the number of strings you've read by assigning a new value to variable `i`.

There may be other problems, too.